# You can implement missing steps with the snippets below

Tags: maven, junit, cucumber

```
>## This my Pom.xml file structure ##
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.cucumberExcecise</groupId>
    <artifactId>Cucumber_Practice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

## Feature File:##
Feature: Login Feature
Scenario: Login as a authenticated user
   Given User is on Home Page
**Step Definition code:**
@Given("User is on Home Page$")
    public void user_is_on_homepage() {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://sample.com");
    }
**Runner Class:**
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(strict = true,features = "src/test/resources/featureFiles/sample.feature", glue = {
        "src/test/java/com/stepDefinitions/Step.java" })

public class TestRunner {

}

**Whenever running Runner class its showing below error:**

1 Scenarios ([33m1 undefined[0m)
1 Steps ([33m1 undefined[0m)
0m0.000s
```

You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

```
    @Given("^User is on Home Page$")
    public void user_is_on_Home_Page() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    }
```

Comment: Consider upgrading cucumber version... Make glue="com.stepDefinitions"

Answer (score 0):

in your Testrunner class you have to put some stuff, or rather it has certain annotations (the class itself is empty)

You have to tell where the Feature files are and where the steps files are (the .java files, this comes in the "glue")

You can also specify tags (then you annotate your features or scenarios with @something to run these )
And there are other options that deal with things like reports.

an example would be:

```
package steps;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/"
        , monochrome = false
        , format = { "pretty", "html:target/results" }
        , glue = { "steps" }
        , strict = true
        , tags = {"@RT-interact"}
)
public class TestRunner {
}
```

There are many tutorials such as http://www.automationtestinghub.com/cucumber-test-runner-class-junit/ where you can find more info.

Comment: Edit: I read to fast, skipping some of the ugly formatted code. I see you did actually have this stuff in your Test Runner. This message usually indicates that there is a mistake in the glue path. Please review that.